# How to use macro annotation on the companion object of case class to generate val for each accessor based on their type

Tags: scala, annotations, accessor, scala-macros

I am trying to generate Lens for all accessors of a case class. Ideally, I would like to obtain something like:

```
case class Person(_name: String, _age: Int)

@Lenses
object Person
```

This would generate the following companion object:

```
object Person {
  val name: Lens[Person, String] = // some implementation
  val age: Lens[Person, Int] =     // some implementation
}
```

I found this [project](https://github.com/kilahsu/macroannot/blob/master/tests/src/main/scala/com/company/product/packagename/MyMacro.scala) that uses macro annotation on companion object to generate a method for each accessor. However, I dont know how to get the type of each accessor and the type of the case class.

Comment: Not an answer, but [Rillit](https://github.com/travisbrown/rillit) contains most of the machinery you'll need (and supports a slightly different syntax, which makes reaching into deeply nested case classes a little easier).

Comment: @TravisBrown Thank you. I am trying to do that for my own Lens library: [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle), so I would like to avoid adding any dependency.

Comment: Right—Rillit is mostly just a proof of concept, anyway. I'll look forward to seeing what you do with Monocle!

Comment: Would it be okay for you to put an annotation on a case class? That would instantly solve all the problems, because then the expansion would see the tree of the case class, and you'll be able to extract all the necessary info.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako yes it would be perfect.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako do you have a link that will show me how to extract the necessary info? Thank you :)

Comment: Replace the q"object ..." pattern in https://github.com/kilahsu/macroannot/blob/master/tests/src/main/scala/com/company/product/packagename/MyMacro.scala#L17 with a pattern for a class definition from http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/syntax-summary.html, and then inspect paramss matched by that pattern. Would that work for you?